# FlashBuildeC native extension 'InputMethodContext' required by the application was not found

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am working on an existing Flex project and I am using FlashBuilder. I would like to use FlashBuilderC and fb.exportReleaseBuild ant task to schedule nightly builds.

It seems I have a problem with native extensions.

> fb.exportReleaseBuild] com.adobe.air.InvalidInputException: An implementation f
>   or native extension 'InputMethodContext' required by the application was not fou
>   nd for the target platform

Using Flash Builder GUI, I can successfully build and package the project

This is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="main">
<target name="main">
    <fb.exportReleaseBuild project="myproject" />
</target>
</project>
```

And this is the script I use

```
set WORKSPACE=path_to_my_workspace

REM works with either FlashBuilderC.exe or eclipsec.exe
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\FlashBuilderC.exe" ^
--launcher.suppressErrors ^
-noSplash ^
-configuration C:\flashbuilderconf ^
-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner ^
-data "%WORKSPACE%" ^
-file "%cd%\build.xml"
```

Am I missing anything?